# When is the case to use pluginlib

Tags: ros, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

follow:[pluginlib](http://ros.org/wiki/pluginlib)

I see all of the documentation in pluginlib.

I think to use of time in pluginlib.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39611/when-is-the-case-to-use-pluginlib/) by [li-an](https://answers.ros.org/users/2411/li-an/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What exactly do you want to know?

If you refer to "what is the purpose of pluginlib":
The pluginlib package provides tools for writing and dynamically loading plugins using the ROS build infrastructure.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [li-an](https://answers.ros.org/users/2411/li-an/) on 2012-07-24**:
In tutorials here is only one package with two algorithms,how is show dynamically loading plugins ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-24**:
You mean the Square/Triangle example? They are loaded dynamically in 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not want to be rude. Are you asking when pluginlib architecture is used?
If yes, then you can have look at navigation stack setup, specifically move_base. Which global planner to use, can be configured in launch files and corresponding library will get loaded. Pluginlib allow to do that.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-07-24**:
dornhege gave more appropriate answer :)